# Encrypted password not reading properly while bean is created in spring

Tags: spring

I am beginner in spring area & tried reaching on this but it seems something is going wrong with my configuration.

Problem statement:
one of encrypted password property is declared in application.properties & its simple as below :

```
server.authentication.external.password={ENCRYPT}5nYRejahndjhsyfvvjehbd==
```

My bean is created like below :

```
public Client externalClient(@Value("${server.authentication.external.username}") String username,
                               @Value("${server.authentication.external.password}") String password){
....
}
```

Issue is expected password to be read with "@Value("${server.authentication.bapi.password}"" should be **"{ENCRYPT}5nYRejahndjhsyfvvjehbd=="** but i am getting **"5nYRejahndjhsyfvvjehbd=="** The prefix didnt readed. Hence my password is working.Trying to understand why this prefix was escaped

Answer (score 0):

why this prefix was escaped because in spring, value of application.properties field should be in string form, it should not contain contain curly brackets like {ENCRYPT} it represents a json object or a map not string. that's why spring is not including and parsing it as value.